# django authorization in class-based view

Tags: django, request, authorization

I'm trying to restrict access of CRUD pages to the owners, but I can't find the class-based view equivalent of "if request.user != post.author raise Http404". Thx for your time.

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

views.py

```
class ArticleUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Article
    fields = ['title', 'body']
    template_name = 'article_edit.html'
    login_url = 'login'
```

I tried the following (and many other combination arround those lines), but it isn't working.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user == self.obj.author:
            raise Http404()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youn can do something like this:-

```
class ArticleUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Article
    fields = ['title', 'body']
    template_name = 'article_edit.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.obj = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user != self.obj.author:
            raise Http404()
        return super(ArticleUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: replace  super(ArticleUpdateView).get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) with this   
super(ArticleUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: just add return in front of super then, like this
 return super(ArticleUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override the `get_queryset` method to achieve this. For example:

```
class ArticleUpdateView(...):

 def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(ArticleUpdateView, self).get_queryset()
    return queryset.filter(author = self.request.user)
```

So, when a user tries to update an post which is not created by him, then he will not be able to get it because will not be able find the post object in Queryset provided by `get_queryset` method. For details, please [SingleObjectMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) which is later sub-classed by UpdateView. *FYI* you don't need to override the `get` method for this implementation.